# How to open microsoft powerpoint app using launcher class(xamarin.essentials)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
private async void SlidesCommandTapped(object obj)
        {
            if (!await Launcher.TryOpenAsync("com.microsoft.office.powerpoint://"))
            {
                await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint"));
            }
}
```

**tryopenasync now working**

if microsoft powerpoint app not present it opens playstore and tells you to install powerpoint app but right now if the app is installed too its going to playstore

Comment: Well isn't your URI asking it to open market always?  `await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint"));`

Answer (score 0):

Well your code should look something like below:

```
var isPowerPointAvailable = await Launcher.TryOpenAsync("com.microsoft.office.powerpoint://");
        if (isPowerPointAvailable)
        {
            // this would change based on what file you want to open
            await Launcher.OpenAsync("com.microsoft.office.powerpoint://");
        }
        else
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint"));
        }
```

Goodluck,

Feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: Thanks But I ended up using dependency service , like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97f3ffba-e095-4917-b705-951d395e3ca5/how-to-open-google-drive-?forum=xamarinforms